# Unirest response hides true exception

Tags: java, json, unirest

When I execute this unirest request

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("myUrl/" + id + "/step")
              .headers(headers)
              .asJson();
```

If the real response is a 401 or anything else (e.g., 404 not found), it gets hidden by the for Json exception:

```
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

If I call `myUrl/" + id + "/step"` directly with bad authentication (from my browser) I do get a 401. The `asJson()` call is hiding the 401. Please suggest a way to solve this (i.e. get the real response 401).

Comment: Why not just split your chained method call into its components?

Comment: @MadPhysicist If I do that i'm not sure how to transfor to Json afterwards. 
HttpRequest req = Unirest.get("myUrl/" + id + "/step").headers(headers); HttpResponse response = req.???; Then what do with response to put into Json (i receive a complex string from myURL API that is different each time..can't be a class)

Comment: Can you link me to the docs for the library you are using?

Comment: import com.mashape.unirest.*      http://unirest.io/java.html